# Don't allow placeholder question title text to be submitted as question title

Tags: bug, questions, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-reject questions titled “what's your programming question? be specific.”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93438/auto-reject-questions-titled-whats-your-programming-question-be-specific)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329155/whats-your-programming-question-be-specific) just popped up, with an initial title of

> what's your programming question? be specific.

which happens to be the placeholder text for the title field. (A proper title has since been added.)

Can the system check if the question title is the placeholder text and reject the submission with an error if it is? I don't know how the placeholder text even gets through in the first place — could be some client-side issues or something, as I do see the text in my browser's autocomplete — but I don't think it's something that should get through anyway, since it isn't a real question title.

Comment: Type your comment here

Comment: @jonsca: enter at least 15 characters

Comment: @BoltClock True, but there's no prompt within the box, so I made it up. 508 characters left.

Comment: blink blink blink blink blink blink blink

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93438/auto-reject-questions-titled-whats-your-programming-question-be-specific

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: Hot diggedy. Voting to close mine.

Comment: I said **related**.  I don't have vote to close on meta anyway.  :-)

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: It does sound like a duplicate though :|

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 14):

This shouldn't be possible, as that placeholder text is an overlaid `<div>` with transparency -- it never actually *appears* in the `<input>` element at any time.

So therefore, I can only surmise this user *actually typed that in as the title*.

Comment: Or, in some way the user selected the text inside the `<div>` and per accident dragged it into the `<input>`.